# Ensuring Orientation of UIView subviews

Tags: iphone

I have a UIView that will eventually contain a child, another UIView.

What I would like to do is ensure that the child is always oriented in the lower left corner of the screen, regardless of orientation. If I add the view at position (0, 0), the subview will remain in the top left corner, regardless of orientation. My question is, how can I get my subview to remain in the lower left corner?

What parameters / autoresizing masks, etc. must I specify when I create the view to get this to happen?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Position the child view in the bottom left corner and configure its `autoresizingMask` property. I've always used Interface Builder to do this for me, so I'm not sure which ones you want to set programmatically, probably something like:

```
View.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

Here is the [documentation for the autoresizing values](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAutoresizing).